# Connect device or app to socks4 server on localhost:port

Tags: java, android, tor, socks, torsocks

I would like to be able to connect to my TOR instance on localhost:generated_port but I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: You can use your system IP address for that.

Comment: What is this system IP? (BTW you can also make an answer so I can give it a checkmark) @RakeshSaini

Comment: You can find it in the network option